# "Account recovery is not available because of a server error. Start over and try again."

Tags: apple-id

So I had to do a lost password/recovery and I got an email from Apple saying I could try a reset.

However, I've tried multiple times and get "Account recovery is not available because of a server error. Start over and try again."

Any ideas?